# Forcing and antichains

Tags: set-theory, forcing

What would be a good way to show:

If $p \Vdash (\exists\alpha)  \phi(\alpha)$, then there is an antichain $A$ maximal below $p$, and a set of ordinal $\{\gamma_{q} | q \in A\}$ s.t. $(\forall q \in A$) $q \Vdash \phi(\gamma_{q})$

Comment: @hot_queen I for one strongly disapprove of changing the notation of the OP. For, it (1) may alienate the OP from their question; (2) introduces a mismatch between Asaf's answer and the question. Plus that $\Vdash$ is not a symbol of the formal language (but rather of the metalanguage) and hence $(\forall q \in A) q \Vdash \phi(\gamma_q)$ is plainly malformed.

Comment: Fortunately, it seems to me, that my editing agrees with the notation Asaf used in his solution :P.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: While I agree in part with your comment, the statement $(\forall q\in A)q\Vdash\phi(\gamma_q)$ is fully formal if you consider forcing in the universe *over a [countable transitive] model* of $\sf ZFC$.

Comment: Dear Lord, I am not very conversant with subtle distinctions between meta/object languages so please excuse my ignorance and reedit the question.

Comment: @hot_queen: I was in a similar place until about a year ago. But I have to admit that once you understand the intricacies of these issues, forcing becomes even clearer and better understood. I strongly recommend you, and pretty much anyone working with forcing, to dwell on the differences between the metalanguage and the language, as well the necessity for models or Boolean-valued universes (the latter allows us to prove independence without actually adding a new generic set, and so we can prove the independence internally, rather than resorting to countable transitive models).

Comment: My problem is that I don't know what Lord's objection was above since I don't see anything wrong with the question as stated.

Comment: And I also do not understand what you mean when you say "... is fully formal if you consider forcing in the universe over a countable transitive model of ZFC".

Comment: @hot_queen Using the $\forall$ quantifier in statements about the metalanguage (which is as I perceived it, prior to Asaf's remark), if not here, then in general, introduces a dangerous mixing between formal and object language. Particularly when dealing with chains of models, this can quickly become confusing and lead to errors. But outside of the context of this specific question, please take on board that editing notation is not good practice, particularly when answers already have been posted.

Comment: I have no idea what @Lord_Farin's objection is, since $(\forall q\in A)q\Vdash\phi(\gamma_q)$ is a set theoretic statement. Not quite a statement in the language of set theory, but the process to rewrite it just using $\in$ and parameters is routine, and no one who loves their sanity would attempt the rewrite anyway. (What meta language is this we are talking about here?) If the objection is that some $\check{}$ are missing, it is routine to suppress them, for readability.

Comment: @Andres As far as I had encountered the $\Vdash$ notation, it has always been on par with $\models$ and $\vdash$, which I usually do not want to consider as part of the same language as the formulae they relate. I have concluded I must have been out of my depth. Apologies; more so as this whole discussion is likely to obfuscate the most important point of not changing the notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the mixing lemma to conclude that there exists a name $\dot x$ such that $p\Vdash\dot x\in\check{\sf Ord}$ such that $p\Vdash\phi(\dot x)$.

Now consider $\{q\leq p\mid\exists\alpha\in{\sf Ord}:q\Vdash\check\alpha=\dot x\}$.

This is a dense [and open] set, so we immediately have that there is only a set of possible ordinal values for $\dot x$, and by thinning it out to a maximal antichain we have as wanted.

Comment: Asaf, not that it matters but you probably meant to write "one can choose a set of possible ordinal witnesses" instead of "there is only a set of possible ordinal value for $\mathring{x}$". For all we know, $\phi(x)$ could be a dumb formula like $x = x$.

Comment: @hot_queen: True, but once you have fixed a name of an element from the ground model there is only a set of possible values for it. What is true is that you may have a proper class of names which $p$ forces to be pairwise different.

Comment: You are right. I made a stupid remark.

Comment: Sorry @AsafKaragila, could you tell me how the mixing lemma is used exactly? I mean, which are the names $\sigma_p$ and the corresponding antichain?.

Moreover, I am not able to understand the statement "so we immediately have that there is only a set of possible ordinal values for $\dot{x}$, and by thinning it out to a maximal antichain we have as wanted". Why are only  a set of possible ordinal values for $\dot{x}$ and how can we pick an antichain inside our set of conditions $q$?

Comment: @Antoine: The term "mixing lemma" is used by various people for various different lemmas. In this case, I mean the statement that if $p\Vdash\exists x\varphi(x)$, then there is some $\dot x$ such that $p\Vdash\varphi(\dot x)$. (In other cases, it means the opposite, that if you have an antichain with names attached to each condition, then you can "mix" them into a single name forced to have that property.)

Comment: @Antoine: For the second part, every possible value for $\dot x$ is determined by at least one condition below $p$. There is only a set of conditions below $p$, so only a set of possible values.

Comment: Thanks @AsafKaragila ! And what about the existence of antichains? Can we consider an antichain inside our set and then use AC to pick a maximal antichain inside it?

Comment: @Antoine: One you have a dense set, it's an easy exercise in transfinite recursion to show it contains a maximal antichain.